# return the index of an array when searched by value

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, algorithm

I have an array from a MySQL result. I want to be able to search by value and get the index position in the array.

**My array `$array_result` given below**

```
Array (
    [0] => Array ( [scores] => 90 ) 
    [1] => Array ( [scores] => 80 ) 
    [2] => Array ( [scores] => 73 )
    [3] => Array ( [scores] => 0 ) 
    [4] => Array ( [scores] => 0 ) 
    [5] => Array ( [scores] => 0 ) 
    [6] => Array ( [scores] => 0 ) 
    [7] => Array ( [scores] => 0 ) 
    [8] => Array ( [scores] => 0 ) 
    [9] => Array ( [scores] => 0 ) 
    [10] => Array ( [scores] => 0 ) 
    [11] => Array ( [scores] => 0 ) 
    [12] => Array ( [scores] => 0 ) 
    [13] => Array ( [scores] => 0 ) 
    [14] => Array ( [scores] => 0 ) 
    [15] => Array ( [scores] => 0 ) 
    [16] => Array ( [scores] => 0 ) 
    [17] => Array ( [scores] => 0 )
)
```

Example: I want to search for `80` and get index of `1`. I have tried this function but am not getting the right response: `array_search(80, $array_result)`.

Comment: This is a multi dimensional array so, `array_search` not work.

Comment: @FrayneKonok thanks which approach do  you think is best?

Comment: @dakab thanks for editing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a foreach loop to achieve this. [Online link](https://3v4l.org/iBsBb), try this one. You first match will return the index.

**Array**

```
$array_result = array( 
    array ("scores" => 90 ), 
    array ("scores" => 80 ), 
    array ("scores" => 73 ), 
    array ("scores" => 0 ), 
    array ("scores" => 0 ), 
    array ("scores" => 0 ), 
    array ("scores" => 0 ), 
    array ("scores" => 0 ), 
    array ("scores" => 0 ), 
    array ("scores" => 0 ), 
    array ("scores" => 0 ), 
    array ("scores" => 0 ), 
    array ("scores" => 0 ), 
    array ("scores" => 0 ), 
    array ("scores" => 0 ), 
    array ("scores" => 0 ), 
    array ("scores" => 0 ), 
    array ("scores" => 0 ) 
);

foreach($array_result as $key => $val){
    if(in_array(80, $val)){
        $out = $key;
        break;
    }       
}

echo $out;
```

**Output**

> 1